# Куди подівся м'який знак зі слова ковзький?

Tags: правопис, орфографія

В [академічних словниках початку ХХ століття](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) маємо написання прикметника *ковзький, сковзький* з м'яким знаком. В [Словнику Української мови онлайн](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=42558&page=1344) і [Орфографічному словнику УМ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) маємо написання без м'якого знака. За якими правилами було змінено написання? Чому м'який знак залишився у слові слизький?

Answer (score 3):

Натрапив на цікавий запис у [Фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/slovopys/posts/1640480222846883:0) стосовно цього питання, тому процитую джерело:

> М'яка вимова звуків характерна риса нашої мови. Розуміючи, що
>   самобутність мови великою мірою залежить від вимови, вороги
>   українського слова взялися знищувати м'якість української мови,
>   прищеплюючи їй невластиве для неї твердомовлення. Так, цілу низку
>   м'яких прикметників після погрому українства у 30-х роках
>   запроваджений тоді післяпогромний правопис (або **правопис
>   Кагановича-Постишева**) обернув на тверді...
>
> Удар було спрямовано на
>   знищення особливостей українського мовлення. Цілий ряд зафіксованих у
>   словнику Грінченка слів з пом'якшенням звуків З та Л після погрому
>   було "затверджено":
>
> У словнику Грінченка
>
> гризький
>
> **ковзький**
>
> колький
>
> смалький
>
> Калічники
>   української мови лишили гризький і колький пом'якшеними, а **смалкий і
>   ковзкий "затвердили"** /і це тоді, коли ховзький (!), а також труський і
>   тряський лишили пом'якшеними/. Треба сказати, що й правопис 1928 р. не
>   до кінця дослідив м'які й тверді форми слів. Правопис визнав твердими
>   прикметники безпросвітний і розпутний. Спосіб же реконструкції
>   дозволяє встановити, що ці прикметники м'які.

І справді, згідно до Вікіпедії є такий [Українській правопис 1933 року](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), а також те, що зміна "ковзького" на "ковзкого" сталася у 30-х роках знаходимо у цьому [джерелі](https://sites.google.com/site/mandrivnyjvolhv/ridna-vira/ridna-mova/knigi/karavanskyj/sekreti/05/39).

Comment: Ще додам, що колись мені у руки попала книга, здається називалася "Таємниця м'якого знака", де також підносилося це питання. На жаль, зараз я не маю змоги нею скористатися, але як тільки мені випаде нагода, я ще й там пошукаю матеріали по цьому питанні.